# Cannot connect to database when setting transactionOption to Required

Tags: ssis, transactions, ssms, rollback

I have several packages in ssis, in the package I have a container which takes data from .csv files and uploads it to a database table using ole db destination. Everything works fine but when I change the transactionoption to required for the container then I get an error:

> ```
> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Failed to acquire connection "sql-data-dev\dev.main_data". Connection may not be configured
> ```
>
> correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this
> connection.

At the same time, I am able to run this query on the SQL Server I am using together with ssis with no issues:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO [data].[testingrollback] (id,name,salary) VALUES (3,'test','200')
    INSERT INTO [data].[testingrollback] (id,name,salary) VALUES (2,'test','200')

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
END CATCH
```

This query worked just the way it should, if the first insert works but the 2nd fails, then no inserts will be made, if both work then both are committed, which indicates that transaction coordinator is running on the SQL Server. It is also running on the PC which SSIS is on.

My connection manager uses Native OLEDB\Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server with windows authentication.

I want a rollback functionality for my container, I am aware that flat file sources don't work with rollbacks, I have tried with containers that just have Execute SQL Tasks and got the same error.